# Programmatically change dropdownlist selected value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, api, browser

I want to create an application that is able to change the selected value of the dropdownlist in the web page.

I tried to use the code below to change the selected value of the dropdownlist:

```
Dim TypeSelection As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("dropdownlist1")
Dim TypeSelectionOption As HtmlElement = TypeSelection.GetElementsByTagName("option").Cast(Of HtmlElement).First(Function(el) el.GetAttribute("value") = "ABC")
    TypeSelectionOption.SetAttribute("selected", "true")
    TypeSelection.InvokeMember("onchange")
```

The selected value of the dropdownlist had been changed, but it can't post back to the server, it just hangs at there. I tried to create a testing page to test my code, the code is working & able to post back to the server.

Is there any other method to change the selected value of the dropdownlist, that is able to post back to the server?

Comment: You are changing the value of an HTML control, these do not postback to the server by default, have you tried using an ASP.NET DropdownList control instead?

Comment: i tried in asp.net dropdownlist..by using my code, the dropdownlist is able to post back to the server